# copy one table data(signup) into another table(login)

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sqldatareader

Now i m working on Crime Diary project in vb.net 2008.

I want to copy one table data (signup) into another table (login)

This is my tables:

**Login**

```
Username            varchar(30)    Unchecked
Password            varchar(30)    Unchecked
```

**Signup**

```
First_Name          varchar(30) Unchecked
Last_Name           varchar(30) Unchecked
Username            varchar(30) Unchecked
Create_Password     varchar(30) Unchecked
Confirm_Password    varchar(30) Unchecked
Birthday            datetime    Unchecked
Gender              varchar(10) Unchecked
Phone_Number        varchar(30) Unchecked
Designation         varchar(30) Unchecked
Batch_Number        int         Unchecked
```

I want to copy two columns in signup(`username` and `confirm_password`) table into login table(`username` and `password`).

Comment: Why not just add a bool column to mark the state rather than repeating data?  Also never ever store passwords as plaintext

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Login
(username,password)
SELECT 
    username,
    confirm_password
FROM Signup
```

**Note:** in this type of operation you should apply where clause, so it will not insert duplicate records